# My code deletes rows when it shouldn't. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

My google sheet javascript program deletes rows even though it shouldn't. My lastDate value is smaller than dates in array. Here is my code:

```
lastDate = new Date(lastDate.setMonth(lastDate.getMonth() - 3))
  ui.alert("Date after mod: " + lastDate)
  for(var i=0;i < values.length; i++)
  {
    if(new Date(values[i][6]).getDate() < new Date(lastDate).getDate() && values[i][6] != "") {
    //if(new Date(values[i][6]).getDate() <= new Date(`${lastDate}`).getDate()){
      row_del.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  for (var i = row_del.length - 1; i>=0; i--)   {     
    sheet.deleteRow(row_del[i]);   }
```

Comment: Can you console log the outcome for new Date(values[i][6]).getDate() and new Date(lastDate).getDate()

Comment: Not enough information. Please provide more details as `console.log('lastDate', lastDate)` and `console.log('values[i][6]', values[i][6])`;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked and the problem was that there was .getDate() method that only comared days instead of full dates. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I checked and the problem was that there was .getDate() method that only compared days instead of full dates. Thanks